# Extract low/okay quality audio from video using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I am new to ffmpeg and I am trying to extract 15 second audio from a video in okay/low quality audio. so far I have `ffmpeg -i {video/audio} -vn` not sure what else to add for do this

Answer (score 1):

Use this for original quality

```
ffmpeg -i {video/audio} -vn -t 15 -c:a copy {output}
```

(extension and format of output will depend on input properties)

and this for okay quality

```
ffmpeg -i {video/audio} -vn -t 15 -c:a aac -b:a 128k output.m4a
```